# Why does \subsubsubsection not work?

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

Why am I not use `\subsubsubsection{My subsubsubsection}`? I tried to use `\paragraph` but same result.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{graphicx}   

\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=3cm,headheight=65pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{tabto}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xspace} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\usepackage{lastpage} 
% References
\usepackage{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{references.bib}    
\usepackage{hyperref} % put here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\hypersetup{pdfstartview = {XYZ null null 1.00}} 
\usepackage{csquotes}

\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}

%HEADER <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<,
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\leftmark }
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-c}}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-c}}
%\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{blabla}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{\thepage /\pageref{LastPage}}}  % added  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\fancyfoot[C]{\fbox{Confidential}} % added  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{sffamily}
            \begin{center}
                
                \begin{figure}[th]
                    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}\hfill
                    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}
                \end{figure}    
                \vspace{3cm}
                %  \textsc{\Large }\\[1.5cm]                    
                % Title
                \HRule \\[0.4cm]
                { \huge \bfseries blabla\\[0.4cm] }
                \HRule \\[1cm]
                %\includegraphics[width=12cm]{images/f5.png}                
                
                % Author and supervisor
                \Large  blabla\\
                \Large{blabla} \\
                \Large blabla\\[1cm]                
                
                \vspace{3cm}
                
                \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
                    \begin{flushleft} \large
                        \emph{\textbf{blabla}}\\ 
                        \textsc{blabla}\\
                        \textsc{blabla}\\
                    \end{flushleft}
                \end{minipage}
                ~
                \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
                    \begin{flushright} \large
                        \emph{\textbf{blabla}}\\
                        \textsc{blabla}\\
                        \textsc{blabla}\\
                    \end{flushright}
                \end{minipage}
                \vfill
                
                % Bottom of the page
                \vspace{1cm}
                {\large 2021 - 2022}
                
            \end{center}
        \end{sffamily}
    \end{titlepage}
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    
    \section{section}
    some content
    \subsection{subsection}
     some content
    \subsubsection{subsubsection}
      some content
    \subsubsubsection{subsubsubsection}
      some content
    
    \vspace{-0.5cm}
    \newpage
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: the command is \paragraph not subsubsubsection. unrelated don't use figure on the title page just use includegraphics directly

Comment: you would not get the same issue from `\paragraph` as that is defined